# Correct way to process lists similar to "StackoverflowQuestion tags"

Tags: jquery, database, web, jquery-select2, database-performance

Having the following tables:

- **Post** (Id, Title, Text, etc.)
- **PostTag**(PostId, TagId)
- **Tag** (Id, Name)

Now the edit form (internet solution) displays the "**tags**" associated to a post by using the Jquery **Select2** control that allows multi entries. This input field returns a list of **tag** Ids.

I think the correct way to process these entries is:

- array loop with an insert statement with not exists condition
- and in the end one delete statement with not exists (to delete the tags that no longer exists).

Or is better to delete all and then insert the new list?

And how about when the table **PostTag** has the fields (`Id, PostId, TagId, CreatedOn`) that allows repeated entries? I believe that any of the two previous ways are correct... and all because the select2 control only return a list of **tag** Ids.

My question applies to the same logic used here in stackoverflow **Questions** where we need to insert the **tags**.

**What is the correct logic to use for this type of data?**

**NOTE:**
The answer I am looking for needs to take in consideration performance and impact on the DB (effects of delete(table lock) / update), I say that because it is easy to make a functional solution that sucks in everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I almost implemented similar tags application six years ago. However, the upper management changed to use sharepoint as the application platform.

1. I agree with you on:

   "I think the correct way to process these entries is:
   array loop with an insert statement with not exists condition
   and in the end one delete statement with not exists (to delete the tags that no longer exists)."
2. Why I am against this idea "delete all and then insert the new list???"

To illustrate my point, I exaggerate a little bit. Imagine that I have a post with 100 tags.

8:00am, I edit the post by adding one tag, and save to database. Then there are 100 deletes and 101 inserts. These operations generate some DML operations, some transaction logs, pages and indexes maintenance on both delete and add operations, etc. If you use an auto ID field in PostTag table, there will be a gap in the ID field because there are 100 deletes.

8:05am, I edit the post by delete one tag, and save to database. Then there are 101 deletes and 100 inserts. The side effects are the same as above.

8:10am, I edit the post by doing nothing, and simply save to database. Then there are 100 deletes and 100 inserts.  The side effects are the same as above.

You can see there are lot of side effects by using this approach even though **there are only one real add and one real delete tag operations**. This will cause serious performance impacts on the database. Since you mention what Stack Overflow will use, imagine that Stack Overflow use this approach, there are 10,000 users edit the 10,000 posts with 10 tags...

3. how about when the table PostTag has the fields (Id, PostId, TagId, CreatedOn) that allows repeated entries?

I would use these fields to implement this feature 'the more entries the better the tags'. This feature is offered in many websites. The more the users click on that tag, the bigger the tag will be.

CreatedOn field can be used later as business intelligence analysis such as when the tags are associated with posts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't event need and ID at Tag table. The same title should be unique in order to don't have spread the info through hundred similar tags. So at PostTag table, the same FK let you make selects with one less join. It also does simple selects with calcs and aggregates just pointing to this table (PostTag)

> Or is better to delete all and then insert the new list???

**I vote for this one**

In java (for example) it's quite easy and faster to remove the collection of "tags" linked to a post than to implement a process that does merge. Because this last one takes longer (it need to calc the difference between what goes in and what goes out). It also has a cost in terms of resources (memory, thread, etc.). To remove a whole list of tags from a Post will take just a very simple statement that any database will execute almost instantly.

The longer is the collection to remove, the longer will be the time that takes to do a merge in runtime instead of executing a simple DELETE statement.

Less loops, less code complexity easier to maintain.

In a *transactional* context all the statments will be commited at same time, so meanwhile, nobody will notice the DELETE. System is still capable to search by tags and involved tags in the managment process will be in any search result.

Finally I didn't understand why PostTag needs a createOn field. Are you going to allow users to create new tags just by typing new tags that were not provided in your list? Then I would suggest a pre-process that takes care of repeated tags.

Over night (or any time you think appropriate) a process that removes massively unreferenced tags. Just to don't let this table grow uncontrollably.

Lets say that your system is going to be used by thousand users, there's a high risk of gather thousands tags alike. That will end up spreading your info, making hard to group it by tags.

"*If i look for entries with tag Java, I don't want to care about similar tags that were typed in lower/uppercase, with '-','#',''s', etc*".

That would be my approach.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend deleting and adding each time for these reasons:

1. A plain old delete or insert by an indexed identifier is going to be very efficient.
2. There's less logic in your code.
3. Testing/debugging will be easier because you know what you see is what you get. If you have 4 tags visible to you in the UI and click save, you know that's exactly what you'll get in the database